# Why uint8 for decimals in ERC20 tokens?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uint256, decimals

Is there a specific reason why pretty much everyone uses uint8 for the decimals in ERC20 tokens?

I would get it if it was to limit the size, because the decimals will never be big enough to exceed the uint8 range and therefore uint256 would be a bit overkill...

However, uint256 does actually cost less gas, because it doesn't need to be downscaled like uint8 does.

So I would like to know, is there a specific reason why uint8 would be preferred? Could it mess up some calculations within ERC20 tokens if uint256 is used?

Answer (score 4):

Well, nothing will mess up if you use uint8 for token decimal.
The reason why most of the ERC20 smart contracts use uint8 for the decimal is that because the EIP-20 propose to use uint8 for decimals.

Please check this use.
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20#decimals

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No , it doesnt mess up the calculations if you use uint256 . In some cases the token details are used as parameter in struct . So if you want to optimize your struct, you can easily do it without changing the other variables . I think this can be one of the reason other reason will be the coding habit, every token decimal is used as a `uint8` so everyone is following it.